# Python, Tkinter, tkFont: Label resize

Tags: python, binding, fonts, tkinter, label

I am trying to get the label to be underlined only when the mouse is over it. I am having trouble with most of it. I think there is an easier way to do this but i have never played around with tkFont. The labels also get resized when the mouse leaves the label.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

def move1(event):
    f = tkFont.Font(lbl1, lbl1.cget("font"))
    f.configure(underline = True)
    lbl1.configure(font=f)

def _move1(event):
    f.configure(underline = False)
    lbl1.configure(font=f)

def move2(event):   
    f = tkFont.Font(lbl2, lbl2.cget("font"))
    f.configure(underline = True)
    lbl2.configure(font=f)

def _move2(event):
    f.configure(underline = False)
    lbl2.configure(font=f)

def move3(event):   
    f = tkFont.Font(lbl3, lbl3.cget("font"))
    f.configure(underline = True)
    lbl3.configure(font=f)

def _move3(event):
    f.configure(underline = False)
    lbl3.configure(font=f)



root=Tk()
root.geometry('100x100+100+100')

f = tkFont.Font()
lbl1 = Label(root, text='Label 1')
lbl1.bind('<Enter>', move1)
lbl1.bind('<Leave>', _move1)
lbl1.pack()
lbl2 = Label(root, text='Label 2')
lbl2.bind('<Enter>', move2)
lbl2.bind('<Leave>', _move2)
lbl2.pack()
lbl3 = Label(root, text='Label 3')
lbl3.bind('<Enter>', move3)
lbl3.bind('<Leave>', _move3)
lbl3.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best solution is to just use two different fonts rather than recreating fonts for every event. Tkinter has the notion of "named fonts", which makes it easy to reference fonts by name when configuring a widget. (named fonts are much more powerful than that, but that's beside the point).

Here's an example where the two fonts are created at the start of the program:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

def on_enter(event):
    event.widget.configure(font="underlined_font")

def on_leave(event):
    event.widget.configure(font="normal_font")


root=Tk()
root.geometry('100x100+100+100')

normal= tkFont.Font(name="normal_font")
underlined = tkFont.Font(name="underlined_font", underline=True)

lbl1 = Label(root, text='Label 1', font="normal_font")
lbl1.bind('<Enter>', on_enter)
lbl1.bind('<Leave>', on_leave)
lbl1.pack()
lbl2 = Label(root, text='Label 2', font="normal_font")
lbl2.bind('<Enter>', on_enter)
lbl2.bind('<Leave>', on_leave)
lbl2.pack()
lbl3 = Label(root, text='Label 3', font="normal_font")
lbl3.bind('<Enter>', on_enter)
lbl3.bind('<Leave>', on_leave)
lbl3.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the exact issue as to why the labels change font size, but I have a solution for the question.

First, that event argument thats being passed in, it contains a reference to the widget that the event happened on, so you don't need two functions for every label anymore.

Secondly, adding `f = tkFont.Font(event.widget, event.widget.cget("font"))` during the `<Leave>` event fixes the issue of the sizes changing.

See below:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

def move1(event):
    f = tkFont.Font(event.widget, event.widget.cget("font"))
    f.configure(underline = True)
    event.widget.configure(font=f)


def _move1(event):
    f = tkFont.Font(event.widget, event.widget.cget("font"))
    f.configure(underline = False)
    event.widget.configure(font=f)

root=Tk()
root.geometry('100x100+100+100')

f = tkFont.Font()
lbl1 = Label(root, text='Label 1')
lbl1.bind('<Enter>', move1)
lbl1.bind('<Leave>', _move1)
lbl1.pack()
lbl2 = Label(root, text='Label 2')
lbl2.bind('<Enter>', move1)
lbl2.bind('<Leave>', _move1)
lbl2.pack()
lbl3 = Label(root, text='Label 3')
lbl3.bind('<Enter>', move1)
lbl3.bind('<Leave>', _move1)
lbl3.pack()

mainloop()
```